# Using sqlalchemy result set for update

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Really 2 questions here.

If I run a sqlalchemy query like this:

```
sensors = session.query(Sensor).filter(Sensor.serial_number.in_(data['sensor_serial_numbers'])).all()
```

Can I then use the result set (sensors) to update a column in all those rows? I couldn't figure out the syntax for that, so I tried doing this:

```
session.query(Sensor).filter(Sensor.serial_number.in_(data['sensor_serial_numbers'])).update({'system_id': system.id})
```

But that fails way down in the bowls of sqlalchemy:

```
  File "/home/ecovent/pyenv0.3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 949, in _do_pre_synchronize
    "Could not evaluate current criteria in Python. "
InvalidRequestError: Could not evaluate current criteria in Python. Specify 'fetch' or False for the synchronize_session parameter.
```

I think that must be because of the in_ clause, as I've done updates before using that same construct, but they did not have an in_ clause. How would I do an update like this with an in_?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try this:

```
session.query(Sensor)\
    .filter(Sensor.serial_number.in_(data['sensor_serial_numbers']))\
    .update({'system_id': system.id}, synchronize_session='fetch')
```

It's documented here: [doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html?highlight=query.update#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update.params.synchronize_session)

The default value is `evaluate` which

> Evaluate the Query’s criteria in Python straight on the objects in the
>   session. If evaluation of the criteria isn’t implemented, an exception
>   is raised.

Comment: Thank you so much. This works. But can you please tell me why this code also works without the `synchronize_session` `session.query(ApplicationInstallation).filter_by(control_hub_id=hub_id).filter(ApplicationInstallation.removal_date == None).update({'removal_date': utc_now})`

Comment: @LarryMartell When you use `in_` whether distinctly or not, a select query is necessary for the MetaData to decide which of its in-memory objects to expire. You can see the select query if echo mode is activated, but I don't know why it's designed like this.

Comment: Can anyone explain "If evaluation of the criteria isn’t implemented, an exception is raised" please? The *fetch* is quite straight forward but the *evaluate* one seems a bit mystery to me ...